# new tags [listening] and [incomprehensibility] should be deleted or become synonymes of [listening-comprehension]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

I've found these two questions tagged with [listening](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/48546/listening-comprehension-of-a-movie-trailer-der-junge-muss-an-die-frische-luft) and [incomprehensibility](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/48181/wie-lautet-dieser-bairische-text-auf-hochdeutsch) and I think, both questions should be re-tagged as [listening-comprehension] (which I've just done, but kept the other tags for the purpose of this question).

I want to suggest

- to make [listening] a synonyme of [listening-comprehension] - it is not possible for me to suggest this at the moment, since the tag scores below 5, but I can see a potential here.
- delete [incomprehensibility]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following tag was removed from all questions:
[incomprehensibility](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/incomprehensibility)

Following synonym was created:
[listening](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/listening) is a synonym and was merged to the master [listening-comprehension](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/listening-comprehension)